# Installing MDB Vue in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, mdbootstrap

I want to install MDB Vue in my fresh Laravel application Im trying to do it via npm but it's not working
I did :
1- created fresh Laravel app
2- Go to the directory www/myApp 
3- `npm install` 
4- `npm install --save mdbvue`
5- `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2`
6- I open app.scss 
and add:

```
// Material Design Bootstrap
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "~mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css";
```

7- I open ressources/js/bootstrap.js
I add:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');

    require('mdbvue');   // I added this!


} catch (e) {}
```

it require('mdbvue') I notice a message  in the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/spW6e.jpg
I can't post it need more reputations

I keep going I did

```
8- npm run dev
```

Everything is green and looking fine but when 
I go take MDB buttons in exemple and put themes in my view it's not working
did I missed something ? help please

Answer (score 0):

Your have to add your imports in the `app.js` file.

```
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 
import 'mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css'
```

For me it works without the `require('mdbvue');` in the `bootstrap.js`.

**But i think the reason you did´nt get an answer for your question is, there are other problems with the integration of mdbvue into the laravel environment.**

For example i have not found a way yet to import fontawesome from my npm-installation folder `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';`.

But when i add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">` to my html-head, fontawesome works.

If i find some solutions, i will update this post.

Hope i could help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I could solved it like this:

1. Cd into your project
2. Run: npm install
3. Run: npm install mdbvue
4. Add the following code to your 'resources/js/app.js' file:

   require('./bootstrap');
       import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
       import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css'
       import 'mdbvue/lib/css/mdb.min.css'
5. Add the following code to your 'resources/js/bootstrap.js' file:

require('mdbvue');

6. Run: npm run dev

It worked for me, using laravel 5.8.35 and the lastest version of MDVUE.